# Поиск Mail.Ru на Python 3.6

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, mail.ru

Я хочу на python сделать запрос в mail.ru. Простой ссылкой не получается сделать. Можете сказать название библиотеки для поиска в Mail.Ru.
А ещё лучше, если скажете библиотеку для поиска в любом поисковике. Я использую python 3.6. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А разве у mail.ru поиска нет своего API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поисковик данные не возвращает как `html` -- результат находится в js-скрипте, по которому рендер построит `html`, что вы и увидете.

Поэтому, нужно загрузить страницу и вытащить тот результат, распарсить его как `json` и показать результат.

Любопытно стало, [вот и накидал пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fdd2e5a2a24bdc6bba26b2125eeee0774905cb24/requests__examples/go.main.ru.py):

```
import requests
import re
import json

rs = requests.get('https://go.mail.ru/search?q=cats')
print(rs)

data = re.search('go.dataJson = (.+);', rs.text)
if not data:
    print('Not data!')
    quit()

data = data.group(1)

rs_data = json.loads(data)
print(rs_data)

for result in rs_data['serp']['results']:
    if 'url' not in result:
        continue

    print(result['url'])
```

Результат:

```
http://mau.ru/
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8_(%D0%BC%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB)
http://cats-crasharena.ru/
http://vk.com/vk.cats
https://trashbox.ru/link/zeptolab-cats-android
https://wooordhunt.ru/word/cats
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=ru&id=com.zeptolab.cats.google
http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4uhxfDlhySxeEQldGsn4TQ
http://anolink.ru/category/igry/battle-cats/
https://www.babla.ru/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/cats
```

---

**PS.** Другой вариант -- использование движка js либо браузера (`selenium`)